# Pointer arithmetic in 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am learning C++. So, please excuse me for this long question.

I have written the below program for arrays. I understand the base address of the array is returned and the name of the array points to that. So, in the case of a 1D array, I can understand that

> arr + 1

returns the address of next item of the array i.e.

> arr + 4bytes

However, in the case of a 2D array, it is a little different. What I understand from the below **cout** statements that in memory arr2D[0], arr2D[1]..arr2D[4] all will be allocated 20bytes one after another as there are 5 cols i.e. **5 * 4 bytes**

arr2D & arr2D[0] points to the same base address as expected; **lines 43 & 45**

So, if I do

> arr2D[0] + 5

I get the address of arr2D[1]; **line 47**. But, when I do

> arr2D + 5

I get a memory address 100 bytes from the base address; **line 50**. I don't understand why. Could anyone explain to me this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int arr[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};

cout << "Printing arr" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cout << *(arr + i) << " ";
}
cout << endl;

cout << "Base address of 'arr': " << (unsigned long) arr
     << " EQUALS " << "&arr: " << (unsigned long) &arr
     << endl;

cout << "Address of 2nd item i.e. i = 1 is: " << (unsigned long) (arr+1)
     << endl;

cout << "arr[1] = " << arr[1] << ", "
     << "1[arr] = " << 1[arr] << ", "
     << "*(arr + 1) = " << *(arr + 1)
     << endl << endl;


int arr2D[5][5] = {{1,2,3,4,5},
                   {3,4,5,6,7},
                   {5,6,7,8,9},
                   {7,8,9,10,11},
                   {9,10,11,12,13}};

cout << "Printing arr2D" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        cout << *(arr2D[i] + j) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;


cout << "Base address of arr2D = " << (unsigned long) arr2D << endl; // this is fine

cout << "Address of arr2D[0] = " << (unsigned long) &arr2D[0] << endl; // this is fine

cout << "Address of arr2D[1] = " << (unsigned long) arr2D[1] << " EQUALS "
     << (unsigned long)(arr2D[0] + 5) << endl; // this is fine

cout << "Address of arr2D[1] = " << (unsigned long) arr2D[1] << " NOT EQUALS "
     << (unsigned long)(arr2D + 5) << endl; // I do not understand this, as arr2D and arr2D[0] is same

cout << "Address of arr2D[1][0] = " << (unsigned long)&arr2D[1][0] << endl;

cout << "arr2D[1][0] = " << *((arr2D[0] + 5) + 0) << endl;
}
```

Comment: A 2D array is an *array of 1D arrays*, so on access, the array is converted to a *pointer to the first 1D array* (which is a pointer to the 2D arrray's first element in a loose sense of the word). If you then derefernce that pointer, the address of the first element in the first array is returned. In both cases that pointer will have **the same address** but the pointers will be **of very different types**. In the first case it is a *pointer to array of int [5]* and in the second case a *pointer to int*. See [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1(p3)](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3)

Comment: It works the same in C++, I just don't have the cross-reference to that standard handy (monthly boot of windows for updates ...)

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-arrays-c-cpp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `arr2D[0]` and `arr2D` point to the same address, but they point to different *types*.

`arr2D[0]` is the first row of the 2D array, therefore it decays to a pointer to the first element of that row (a single int). Meanwhile, `arr2D` is a 2D array (an array of arrays), so it decays to a pointer to the first row (a 5 element array).

As you know, pointer arithmetic is scaled to the size of the objects being pointed to by a pointer. Since `arr2D` points to 5 element int arrays, each object being pointed to has a size of 4*5=20 bytes (assuming 32-bit ints) so increasing the pointer by 5 results in a difference of 20*5=100 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array):

> When array-to-pointer decay is applied, a multidimensional array is
> converted to a pointer to its first element (e.g., a pointer to its
> first row or to its first plane): array-to-pointer decay is applied
> only once

So arr2D decayed into a pointer to an int array of size five, and the size of that is 20.